# .trigger("change") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress WooCommerce theme, but I ran into a issue..
I've made quantity increment buttons which work, but after the click event I want to trigger the update cart button but the button is disable by WooCommerce and a change event on the quantity input field is needed for that to happen. I've tried .trigger('change') and .change(). Both didn't work can you help me out?

```js
$('.quantity').on('click', '.plus', function(e) {
  $input = $(this).prev('input.qty');
  var val = parseInt($input.val());
  var step = $input.attr('step');
  step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
  $input.val(val + step).trigger('change');
});
$('.quantity').on('click', '.minus', function(e) {
  $input = $(this).next('input.qty');
  var val = parseInt($input.val());
  var step = $input.attr('step');
  step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
  if (val > 0) {
    $input.val(val - step).trigger('change');
  }
});

$('.qty').on('change', function() {
  alert('.qty has changed!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="" name="cart[256a54619faec7a3f96b726a46dae520][qty]" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

In this snippet it works, but on my localhost it doesn't

Comment: Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: Are you using the same version of jquery in your project? I believe it's wordpress and it might be shipped with a version of jquery that doesn't support the js snippet. Also, if you have more than one version of jquery on your page, you can have this kind of issues.

Comment: No I din't get a error

Comment: My project is using jQuery 2.1.4, the snippet works with that too

Comment: The problem is not the triggering of a change event... WooCommerce just doesn't register the event

Comment: Try to wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code inside here */ })`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.quantity input').on('click', function(e) {
  $input = $(this).parent().find("input.qty");
  var step = $input.attr('step');
  var val = parseInt($input.val());
  step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;

  if( $(this).val() == "+" ) {
    $input.val(val + step);
  } else {
    $input.val(val - step);
  }

  $input.trigger("change");
});

$('.qty').on('change', function() {
  alert('.qty has changed!');
});
```

Comment: This works with the trigger, but still the update button in wordpress doesn't register the change

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution for forcing the cart to update, when quantity is changed, without clicking the "update cart" button. Please mind that it also works when button is `disabled`

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_cart_refresh_update_qty' ); 
function wp_cart_refresh_update_qty() { 
    if (is_cart()) { 
        ?> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.quantity input', function(){
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
                jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); 
            }); 
        </script> 
        <?php 
    } 
}
```